# C# User Interface Printing Image on Screen Problem

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to print images when user clicks on buttons. The first click works fine and prints the image but other clicks do not work as I expect. Even I click on another button first image is shown. For example when I click to chef's it prints correct images then I click on veg but it still shows the images of chef's. What is the problem of this code?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> selectedMenu = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ObservableCollection<string> ChefsMenu = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> VegMenu = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> LowCMenu = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> orders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
private void ChefsButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            chefFlag = true;
            vegFlag = false;
            lowFlag = false;
            int len = ChefsMenu.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                selectedMenu.Add(ChefsMenu[i]);
            }
            ShowPanel.ItemsSource = null;
            ShowPanel.Items.Refresh();
            ShowPanel.ItemsSource = selectedMenu;
        }

        private void VegButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            chefFlag = false;
            vegFlag = true;
            lowFlag = false;
            int len = VegMenu.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                selectedMenu.Add(VegMenu[i]);
            }
            ShowPanel.ItemsSource = null;
            ShowPanel.Items.Refresh();
            ShowPanel.ItemsSource = selectedMenu;
        }

        private void LowCButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            chefFlag = false;
            vegFlag = false;
            lowFlag = true;
            int len = LowCMenu.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                selectedMenu.Add(LowCMenu[i]);
            }
            ShowPanel.ItemsSource = null;
            ShowPanel.Items.Refresh();
            ShowPanel.ItemsSource = selectedMenu;
        }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" Name="ShowPanel" ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=selectedMenu}" Width="690" Height="320">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="LightGreen" BorderThickness="0.5">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="97" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have instanciated the **selectedMenu** object only once at the start of the class like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> selectedMenu = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

From that moment, everytime you click on a button, the corresponding elements are added to the selectedMenu. If there were some previous items, they are not removed.

So add a call to the clear method at the beginning of each button's click event handler, something like:

```
selectedMenu.Clear()
```

You will do that in three places since you have three button click event handlers. After that, whenever you click on any of the buttons, the former items are first removed before the new items are added.